# XML Schema regex "/" and "|"

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have three different pattern values in an XML Schema:

1. `"[A-Z0-9]{1,12}"`
2. `"([A-Z0-9]{2})|"`
3. `"([A-Z0-9 /]{1,25})|"`

My interpretation of example 1 is value can contain between 1 and 12 capital letters or digits between 0 and 9.

I'm confused about the `or` symbol at the end of example 2.  Or what? Since the or symbol is at the end of the statement.

In example 3 what does the `/` do?  Same question above as it applies to the trailing `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([A-Z0-9]{2})|`: two capital letters or digits, ***or nothing***.

`([A-Z0-9 /]{1,25})|`: 1 to 25 capital letters, digits, space chars, or `/` chars, ***or nothing***.  Alternatively: `([A-Z0-9 /]{0,25})`